# Boost exception after connect()

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

```
NetworkInterface::NetworkInterface(void):
    sock(io_service)
{
    // ------------------
    // CONNECT TO SERVER
    // ------------------
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    string ip = "127.0.0.1";
    tcp::resolver::query query(ip, "daytime");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

    sock.connect(*endpoint_iterator);
}
```

I'm trying to make this work but after the connect method gets called I get a runtime exception:

```
Unhandled exception at at 0x754E2EEC in TestClient.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> > at memory location 0x0072F140.
```

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. The thing I'm trying to do is get the sock variable to be used in the whole class (so I've declared it in the header as you may have noticed).

EDIT:
As for includes, I included the boost root in the include directories thing. And the boost root/stage/lib path in the library directories. I also added a lib file to the additional dependencies thing. (Properties -> Linker -> Input)

Comment: Boost exceptions usually carry a message. What does it say in your case?

Comment: It doesn't say anything. I only got that message. In the call stack there's nothing useful except for the fact that you can see that a Boost error has occured (with no useful information that is)

Comment: Try catching the exception, you should then be able to print `error->what()`. Although I wonder why the debugger cannot display it..

Comment: Another thing I just noted.. in which order do you declare `sock` and `io_service`? Keep in mind that fields are constructed in the order they were declared, so maybe you're initializing `sock` with an uninitialized `io_service`

Comment: I am indeed initializing sock with an uninitialized io_service. The problem is I can't seem to do it AFTER initializing io_service because sock doesn't have normal constructor or something

Comment: I got it. The error is: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
That's because I don't have a "server" running atm. Got it fixed now. Thanks for the help. (Add your comment as a question so I can flag it as resolved by you maybe?)

Comment: You're welcome :) I just posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By catching the exception, you should be able to see the actual error message, so you can see what the actual issue is:

```
NetworkInterface::NetworkInterface(void):
   sock(io_service)
{
    try {
        // your code here..
    } catch (const std::exception& error) {
        // Should print the actual error message
        std::cerr << error.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```